# why nodemon is throwing error that script is disabled?

Tags: node.js

[image]

I have installed nodemon globally,but while trying to run it's showing the error as in image. What to do? Also my node js and projects are in different drives.

Answer (score 0):

There are many of this type issues when you search for them. The best guide I found is:

https://dev.to/thetradecoder/how-to-fix-error-nodemon-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system-34fe

Step 1:
Open Windows PowerShell with Run As Administrator.

Step 2:
As you see the error is about_Execution_Policies, first to see what's there in the present execution policy. Use this command on Windows PowerShell to get it

> **Get-ExecutionPolicy**

Here you'll see 'Restricted'. So, this is the main reason- running scripts on this system is 'Restricted'.

Step 3:
Now we need to change this policy to allow the operation. Use this command to make it Unrestricted -

> **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

Here you'll get a prompt message. Press Y to change it

That's it. To ensure, you may check the execution policy status by this command again

> **Get-ExecutionPolicy**

You'll get the output 'Unrestricted'

The problem is solved. Now you can use nodemon on your machine.

Comment: @SwarnabhaRoychowdhury mark it as answer so can count this one as resolved